# Prevent editing of pull request comments

Tags: github, azure-devops, gitlab, pull-request

Does anyone know of a way to prevent comments in a pull request being edited after the request has been completed? Essentially when the review has finished and the branch is merged, we can't allow the review to be changed. Just like this request: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-22517

Or alternatively, do any of the mainstream git platforms have this feature? I have checked the usual Azure DevOps, Bitbucket, Gitlab etc. Maybe there is a tick box somewhere for this?

(Btw, Yes you can just ask developers but we need to show auditors that the comments haven't changed. A bit like branch policies ensure a certain flow)

Comment: Although it's clear what you're asking, unfortunately as it stands I don't think this is a good question due to the fact that it's too open ended and is essentially asking for a product recommendation. (Is there a product that does X?) I suspect this question will be closed. That being said, one thing you can do is use an API to poll (or perhaps trigger anytime a PR/MR is updated) and store all comments. If they ever change at least *you* will have a log of it. Having to do that is annoying, but it would accomplish your goal. If implemented it could be a set and forget until you need it...

Comment: Another thing you can (possibly) do is remove the part of the workflow that requires comments to have meaning once a PR is completed, and use only the approvals instead. That way the auditor won't care about the comments.